# How do I split a JS string by ) or = ?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How do I split a JS string by `)` or `=` ? 
I know I should use a regex with `split()` but dont know the exact regex I should use. Tried this `mystring.split("[\\=\\)]+")` but doesnt work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript, wrapping the regex in quotes won't work. You have to wrap it in slashes:

```
> 'hello)world=yes'.split(/[=)]+/)
["hello", "world", "yes"]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
result = mystring.split(/[)=]/);
```

works. You do need to assign the result back to another (or the same) string, though.